# Retrofit 2 with http on android

Tags: android, http, retrofit2

I have read quite a few resources and tutorials so far, and I still haven't found the solution I need.
The problem is that my application using Retrofit 2 does not send requests to my own server. Empirically, it was revealed that requests are not sent only to addresses using http. Requests were sent to https.

As a solution to this problem, I added the SSL key to my server (My server is written on Spring). Now requests are at least being sent. However, due to the fact that the key that I generated is not confirmed, the application still does not want to make requests for the links I need.

Question: how can you configure Retrofit 2 so that it works with http?

UPD: there is repo with some code from project:https://github.com/Parocq/AuthScreenApp

Comment: Please share the code you tried.

Comment: enable cleartext traffic in manifest

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved with enabling cleartext traffic in manifest.
Two strings was added:
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
and
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.xxx.xxx.xxx">

<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
</application></manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the retrofit documentation https://square.github.io/retrofit/, and also did a quick look at their source code, and as far as I could see there is really nothing in there that cares about HTTP vs HTTPS.

I would suggest trying your app on a device or emulator running a pre-Pie version of Android, just to verify that everything works as expected with your plain HTTP requests.  If it does, then I think the next step is to double-check your network security configuration, as suggested by @Bek.  In case you have not found this article yet, here is a good place to start: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

I'm know this is at best a 'partial answer' (if even that) but I decided to post it based on the SO answer tips.  I hope it can at least help you get unstuck or help you improve your question, and can be updated at some point with actual specific information on your question.

Update:
Looks like you found the real answer, that was quick! https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751722/1245561